# How to get a confirmation box using Asp.Net Webform And Ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am building a user profile update web form using asp.net and ajax. All i need a code that helps me in confirming data update, using if else condition in c#, 
like if data is updated it should return true else false.

Here is my code of .net

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static bool UpadateUserInfo(string first_name, string  last_name, string  p_word, string  email_address, string  gender) 
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPADTE SignUp SET first_name = @first_name, last_name = @last_name, p_word =@p_word, email_address = @email_address, gender = @gender", conn)) 
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", first_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", last_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_word", p_word);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_address", email_address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Best Regards,
Thank You.

Comment: Do you have an error to debug? Or at least a description of what is not working as expected? Just dumping code and saying 'it doesn't do what I need' is not helpful.

Comment: `"SignUp.aspx.cs/EmailAddressCheck"` this doesn't look correct - try `"SignUp.aspx/EmailAddressCheck"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry for that, when i stop typing on the text box it should show an label error that the "user with this email address already exits", but it is not working.

Comment: Add `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); }` to your `$.ajax` to see what the error is.  If it's a 404 then you have the wrong url.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

Dear @freedomn-m it is showing this error on debugging.

Comment: Yes, your URL is incorrect

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your reply, i will check what can i do.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have also posted the img, the url seems fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m what else i can do?

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then the url *path* is **not** "fine".  **No URLs would ever have `.aspx.cs` in the path.**

Comment: @freedomn-m ok let me check again

Comment: Apologies, it's been too many years since I did webforms.  The url with .cs certain looks wrong and unlikely.  But exactly what the url should be or how you configure your webmethod to accept the url and/or POST (if needed) will need to be solved by someone with more recent knowledge.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong call

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtEmailAddress").blur(function() {
    var email_address = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "SignUp.aspx/EmailAddressCheck",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        email_address: email_address
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(html) {
        $("#lblCheckUserEmail").html();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Manish Singh yes i have changed that, the problem was i was using protected modifier for  my method, the error is gone but still it is not hitting the method.

Comment: Try to change the name of variable `email_address` by another, it can have a confusion with the name `email_address` of your method